# Block average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to take average of delta time interval between rows in SQL Server that represent the time occurred between two consecutive operations. However, there are no operations during nights / holidays / weekends (e.g. between the last operation of Friday and the first one on Monday the delta time is more than 48h, but i don't want to consider it), so the average time is totally incorrect.

How to deal with this problem? Is there a way to drop these entries and compute the real average delta time, doing a sort of block (per-day?) average?

Thanks!

An example:

```
Time
00:00:37
00:00:32
00:00:25
...
00:01:22
00:00:54    ---- e.g. Night ---
09:34:12    <--- Exclude this from the average calculation ---
00:00:22
00:00:41
00:00:36
...
```

Desired output

```
Avg time: 41.13s
```

Comment: You would do well to show some example data and your expected output.

Comment: If the two timestamps don't fall on the same date then ignore.

Comment: U'r both right. I added an example anyway.
@shawnt00 how to do it?

Comment: It would help to show more example data. Eg do you have date/ start time/ end time? If so you can use those to set your business rules - eg ignore if a different date. If you literally just had this one column (seems unlikely) then you could set an arbitrary limit (eg 1 hour/ 8 hours...) by adding ```WHERE Time <  '00:08:00'``` for example

Comment: @JShark I have a column with complete timestamps (e.g 2020-11-26 09:25:06.000), i have showed the above example just for sake of simplicity

Comment: `case when cast(dt as date) = cast(lag(dt) over (order by dt) as date) then datediff(second, lag(dt) over (order by dt), dt) else null end as sec`

Comment: Thanks, also your solutions are great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time difference, you can apply a `where` clause.  For the rest, just date functions and arithmetic:

```
select convert(date, time),
       avg( datediff(second, prev_time, time) * 1.0 ) as avg_seconds
from (select t.*,
             lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time
      from t
     ) t
where time < dateadd(hour, 4, prev_time) -- or whatever the threshold is
group by convert(date, time);
```